# How to stop Wordpress search abuse?

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress site is experiancing high load because of large numbers of GET request like:

```
/?s=1ce83ab566d6797d400bd3d03bb45946
```

How to prevent this?

- 17.121.115.141 - [04/May/2022:10:14:35 +0200] "GET /?s=1ce83ab566d6797d400bd3d03bb45946 HTTP/1.1" 301 162 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15 (Applebot/0.1; +http://www.apple.com/go/applebot)"
- 17.121.113.51 - [04/May/2022:10:14:36 +0200] "GET /?s=3fd029d9d203bf707937880d62627b28 HTTP/1.1" 200 20806 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15 (Applebot/0.1; +http://www.apple.com/go/applebot)"
- 17.121.113.65 - [04/May/2022:10:14:37 +0200] "GET /?s=cf68450a505a31b8e0a184d4dda87b76 HTTP/1.1" 200 20800 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15 (Applebot/0.1; +http://www.apple.com/go/applebot)"
- 17.121.115.141 - [04/May/2022:10:14:37 +0200] "GET /?s=71fb944844071f19565b438ec3050fb8 HTTP/1.1" 301 162 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15 (Applebot/0.1; +http://www.apple.com/go/applebot)"
- 17.121.114.42 - [04/May/2022:10:14:38 +0200] "GET /?s=92128e8331f93e466514f6702ed3b06f HTTP/1.1" 200 20798 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15 (Applebot/0.1; +http://www.apple.com/go/applebot)"

Comment: Have you read Apple's documentation at http://www.apple.com/go/applebot?

Comment: We get this question quite a lot. The answer is "Welcome to the Internet". If you expose something, it will get probed. You can't stop people from accessing the site. You might be able to reduce the number of times the same IP hits your site.